# using select function with dataframe to store an item

Tags: r

I am trying to store an object in a particular column of a portion of my dataset. Unfortunately, the selection using the df[[x]] position is not working.

Some random data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) 



 level=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree","Disagree", "Strongly disagree",NA)

data <- data.frame(pre_1=as.character(sample(c("Yes","No", NA), 20, replace = T)), 
                   post_1=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                   original_1=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                   post_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                   original_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                   pre_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                   stringsAsFactors=T)
```

I want to replace the original column with the modified one with numeric factors in a portion of the dataset which in this case are the columns starting with "pre_" and "post_". I want to leave the other columns untouched. Note that i need to use an if statement condition to get the desired columns. In this case, i need to exclude the first column pre_1 since it's just with yes/no and it would be filled up with NAs. What i need to do is tell my function where to write the modified columns and i cannot do it with select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[[i]]

The error is:

```
Error in select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[[i]] = as.numeric(factor(select(data,  : 
  could not find function "select<-"
```

Using `data[[2]]` obviously works but since i am doing this only for a portion of the dataset in a loop i cannot use it. The loop that i am building should modify the check and modify each columns in my dataset. This is the code for the function that I am building.

```
select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_")) %>% 
  length() %>% 
  seq(1,.,1)  %>% 
  for (i in .){
    if (dummy(as.character(select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[[i]])) == FALSE) {
      if (colSums(select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[i] == "Agree", na.rm = TRUE) > 0){
        select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[i] %>% transmute_all(funs(factor(., levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree","Neither agree or disagree", "Agree","Strongly Agree"), ordered = T)%>% as.numeric())) 
      }}}
```

Any help is appreciated

Expected output for 1st 6 rows

```
 pre_1      post_1          original_1                              post_2      original_2                      pre_2
1    No     3               Neither agree or disagree               3           Strongly disagree                  5
2   Yes     5               Agree                                   4           Strongly disagree                  4
3   Yes     5               Neither agree or disagree 3             2           Disagree                           4
4  <NA>     5               Disagree                               <NA>         Disagree                           3
5   Yes     4               <NA>                                    1           <NA>                               5
6    No     5               Strongly disagree                      <NA>         Neither agree or disagree          2
```

Comment: 1st comment: What is use of `select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))`? The `data` got 4 columns and this `select` will return all 4 columns. 2nd comment: `seq(1,.,1)` is as good as seq(1, ncol(data),1`

Comment: What is expected output? Please provide as that will help others to answer your question.

Comment: 1) I tried with ncol but it does not keep the name of the columns for some reasons.
2) I modify the initial data to make the output more explicit

Comment: I think if you can provide expected output then people will have better chance to answer your query. You have done all good work except providing expected output

Comment: Tried to make it more detailed :)

Comment: I can tell you a easy way. Take `head(data)`. Modify the `original_1` column with expected value and add that column as part of your question.

Comment: I want to I want to leave the other columns (in this case "original" ) untouched.

Comment: I have added 6 rows from your dataframe. If you can modify it and show us what exactly you want then people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how i resolved.

```
data = mutate_if(data, array(sapply(data,function (x) !dummy(x))) & array(sapply(data, function (x) colSums(as.matrix(x)=="Agree",na.rm = T) >0)) & (startsWith(names(data),"pre_") | startsWith(names(data),"post_")), funs(factor(., levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree","Neither agree or disagree", "Agree","Strongly Agree"), ordered = T) %>% as.numeric(.)))
```

The dummy function is here

```
dummy <- function(v, naVal = NULL) { 
      v1 <- na.omit(v)
      # remove NA's
      v2 <- as.integer(as.factor(v1))
      if( !is.numeric(v2) ) stop("Only numeric vectors are accepted.")
      # get unique values
      v_unique <- unique(v2)
      # remove 'naVal's
      v_unique2 <- v_unique[! v_unique %in% naVal]
      # count number of unique values and check whether all values are integers
      if ( length(unique(v_unique2)) > 2L || 
           any(as.integer(v_unique2) != v_unique2) ) FALSE else TRUE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find the `mutate_at` function does what you are looking for.  The `select` function returns a subset of the *columns* of the data set, it does not modify them.  The `mutate` functions modify columns, and (in particular) `mutate_at` lets you choose which columns you wish to change.

I *think* this will give you what you are looking for, but you might need to change it slightly since I'm not 100% sure I understand the output you are trying to get.

```
data %>%
  mutate_if(str_detect(names(.), "(pre|post)_[[2-9]]"),as.numeric)
```

Comment: your approach works for me in this way
`data %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pre_"),starts_with("post_") ), ~ factor(., levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree","Neither agree or disagree", "Agree","Strongly Agree"), ordered = T) %>% as.numeric())`

My problem is that I need to perform certain operations on selected columns. In this case i need to exclude the first column with yes /no otherwise it would be filled with NAs. I am using an If statement as shown in my function. What i need to do is thus tell my function where to write the modified columns and i cannot do it with select.

Comment: For now i am stuck here

`select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_")) %>% 
  length() %>% 
  seq(1,.,1)  %>% 
  for (i in .){
    if (dummy(as.character(select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[[i]])) == FALSE) {
      if (colSums(select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[i] == "Agree", na.rm = TRUE) > 0){
        select(data, starts_with("pre_"), starts_with("post_"))[i] %>% transmute_all(funs(factor(., levels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree","Neither agree or disagree", "Agree","Strongly Agree"), ordered = T)%>% as.numeric())) 
      }}}`

Comment: Okay, so you want all the "pre" and "post" values changed except the first one?

Comment: In general, i want to change those columns that met a series of conditions. In this particular case, i want to change the all the columns which start with pre_ & post_ but that are not dummys. So yes, except the first one.

Comment: Ok - I've got something that should work for you.  See edits above.

Comment: Nope, it's not what i am looking for since is not always the first column that is a dummy. Btw thanks for all the help i come up with an answer